# Weird result in php

Tags: php, html, preg-match

Why the output of this code is "true" ?

```
<?php

if (preg_match("/^[Äª]+$/", "ê")) {
    die("true");
} else {
    die("false");
}

?>
```

The result should be false not true!

Comment: Character encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strings are unicode, so if you want the preg_match to work on a unicode string you should add the `u` modifier:

```
if (preg_match("/^[Äª]+$/u", "ê")) {
```

Comment: Learn something new every day hehe